# Javascript remove object from array based on greater date key

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this -

```
"formats": [
{
    "format": "eBook",
    "published": "3/3/2014",
    "id": "1234"
},
{
    "format": "Paperback",
    "published": "19/3/2020",
    "id": "123"
},
{
    "format": "eBook",
    "published": "19/3/2020",
    "id": "12345"
}]
```

and I would like to write a js filter function that should return me based on the latest format.So something like this

```
"formats": [
{
    "format": "Paperback",
    "published": "19/3/2020",
    "id": "123"
},
{
    "format": "eBook",
    "published": "19/3/2020",
    "id": "12345"
}]
```

Where object with id 1234 is removed because another object with the same format (eBook) has a greater published date.

I tried using JS's filter function, but somehow I am messing it up.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const formats = [
{
    "format": "eBook",
    "published": "3/3/2014",
    "id": "1234"
},
{
    "format": "Paperback",
    "published": "27/3/2020",
    "id": "123"
},
{
    "format": "Paperback",
    "published": "19/3/2020",
    "id": "123"
},
{
    "format": "eBook",
    "published": "19/3/2020",
    "id": "12345"
}];

function filterFormats(formats){
    const toTime = (date) => new Date(date.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, "$2/$1/$3")).getTime();
    const data = formats.reduce((a, b) => {
      if(b.format+'' in a && toTime(a[b.format].published) > toTime(b.published)) return a;
      a[b.format] = b;
      return a;
    }, {});
    return Object.values(data);
}

console.log(filterFormats(formats));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```js
    const formats =  [
    {
        "format": "eBook",
        "published": "3/3/2014",
        "id": "1234"
    },
    {
        "format": "Paperback",
        "published": "19/3/2020",
        "id": "123"
    },
    {
        "format": "eBook",
        "published": "19/3/2020",
        "id": "12345"
    }]
    
    
    const getDateObj = (str) => new Date(str.split('/').map(i => i.length<2 ? `0${i}` : i).reverse().join('-'));
    
    const getFilteredArrayOfLatestEntriesForFormats = (formatsArr) => {
     const formatToLatestEntriesMap = formatsArr.reduce((latestFormatEntryMap,obj) => {
      const publishedAt = getDateObj(obj.published);
      if(!latestFormatEntryMap[obj.format] || latestFormatEntryMap[obj.format].publishedAt<publishedAt){
    
       latestFormatEntryMap[obj.format] = {
        ...obj,
        publishedAt: publishedAt
       };
      }
      return latestFormatEntryMap;
     },{})
    
     return Object.keys(formatToLatestEntriesMap).map(format => {
      delete formatToLatestEntriesMap[format].publishedAt;
      return formatToLatestEntriesMap[format];
     })
    }
    
    console.log(getFilteredArrayOfLatestEntriesForFormats(formats));
```